# Bandit issue B108:hardcoded_tmp_directory and B102:exec_used

Tags: python-3.x, django, bandit-python

I ran bandit on my project and got the following issue for security, I don't understand why this is an issue and what are the solutions for the issues.

```
   --------------------------------------------------
>> Issue: [B108:hardcoded_tmp_directory] Probable insecure usage of temp file/directory.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: Medium
   Location: abc/xyz/xxx.py:176
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b108_hardcoded_tmp_directory.html
175         def get_pickle_file_path(self):
176             return os.path.join("/tmp/aaa", "folder_" + self.name)
177 
--------------------------------------------------
>> Issue: [B102:exec_used] Use of exec detected.
   Severity: Medium   Confidence: High
   Location: abc/models.py:1405
   More Info: https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b102_exec_used.html
1404            loc = {'result': []}
1405            exec(self.code, globals(), loc)
1406            return loc['result']
```

After searching for the solution of [B108](https://bandit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/b108_hardcoded_tmp_directory.html) issue. I found [this](https://github.com/Kinto/kinto/commit/5c365d9fb5cdcd336ceefe459c8a14969b07eebc) where `/tmp` is replaced by `tempfile.gettempdir()` function, but the value of the both is same. Is `tempfile.gettempdir()` the solution for `/tmp`?

Answer (score 3):

Just came across this Bandit issue as well. The first link you shared now links to a [resource explaining](https://security.openstack.org/guidelines/dg_using-temporary-files-securely.html) the issue and methods of resolving it.

The main issue appears to be that creating predictable temp files leaves you open to a "time of check, time of use attack (TOCTOU)".
From the resource:

> Malicious users that can predict the file name and write to directory containing the temporary file can effectively hijack the temporary file by creating a symlink with the name of the temporary file before the program creates the file itself. This allows a malicious user to supply malicious data or cause actions by the program to affect attacker chosen files.

`tempfile.gettempdir()` and setting umask to 0077 to ensure only the creator can edit and read seem to be the best solution.

From that resource as well:

```py
import os
import tempfile

tmpdir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
predictable_filename = 'myfile'

# Ensure the file is read/write by the creator only
saved_umask = os.umask(0077)

path = os.path.join(tmpdir, predictable_filename)
print path
try:
    with open(path, "w") as tmp:
        tmp.write("secrets!")
except IOError as e:
    print 'IOError'
else:
    os.remove(path)
finally:
    os.umask(saved_umask)
    os.rmdir(tmpdir)
```